# Unity: Audio Manager for different scene music

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have a background music to play seamlessly from “Scene1” to “Scene2” but I want the music to change if I load “Scene3” or “Scene4” (which should have the same behavior). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Apply code to run from your audio manager which as pointed out should be marked not to destroy and have it respond to the event scenemanager.activescenechanged see documentation

Answer (score 0):

First your music playing gameobject should be using DontDestroyOnLoad functionality, so the music player does not destroy when the scene changes. If you're not using it, read about it here : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

After that, the music player could use [SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) to decide if it should switch the track or not on scene change.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this in Unity forums [SOLUTION](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1260393/make-music-continue-playing-through-scenes.html)

```
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class MusicClass : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private AudioSource _audioSource;
     private void Awake()
     {
         DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
         _audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
     }
 
     public void PlayMusic()
     {
         if (_audioSource.isPlaying) return;
         _audioSource.Play();
     }
 
     public void StopMusic()
     {
         _audioSource.Stop();
     }
 }
```

If you want it to change after just change the audio clip like [HERE](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-clip.html)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip otherClip;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        audio.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(audio.clip.length);
        audio.clip = otherClip;
        audio.Play();
    }
}
```